# SQL query to transpose some columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, crosstab

I have a table like this 3 columns:
**col1,col2,col3**

I have to group these three column and calculate the count.
I have completed the group by like below:

```
select col5,col3,col2, count(*) from mytable group by col5,col3,col2

COL5    COL3    COL2    COUNT(*)
MOVIL   A       PRE     81.00
MOVIL   B       COM     466.00
MOVIL   A       COM     947.00
```

There are only two possible value's in col2 which are PRE and COM
But What I need is a small change like below:

```
COL5    COL3    PRE    COM
MOVIL   A       81     947
MOVIL   B       NULL   466
```

I believe PIVOT should be used for this.
But I am not an expert in SQL. Could anybody please help?

Comment: Can you provide test data with more cases? Can be several 'PRE' and 'COM' on single COL5    COL3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PIVOT like this (I think col2 is having only two values and not col3):

```
SELECT *
FROM (select col5,col3,col2, count(*) from mytable group by col5,col3,col2)
PIVOT(MAX(CNT) FOR COL2 IN ('PRE','COM'));
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer as I like this solution more even though stan's solution is good for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  col5,
  col3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN col2='PRE' THEN count ELSE 0 END) as PRE,
  SUM(CASE WHEN col2='COM' THEN count ELSE 0 END) as COM
FROM (select col5,col3,col2, count(*) as count 
      from mytable group by col5,col3,col2) as sub
GROUP BY col5, col3
```

Like this?

Comment: Sorry for that previous comment. Its working perfectly. Thanks a lot Stan

Comment: @StanislavL : I guess there is no need of "as" keyword while providing alias to an inline view.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot :

```
         select col5 ,col3,[PRE],[COM]
             from
            (
             select col5,col3,col2, count(*) as count 
                  from #Mytable group by col5,col3,col2
                     )c 
            pivot
            (
            max(count)
                   FOR col2 IN ([com],[pre])
            )as p
```

if you have any concern let me know.